# How to set imageview from Image Arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-imageview, android-image

I am using [this](https://github.com/nguyenhoanglam/ImagePicker) library but they did not explain all details like other libraries on the github.

in onCreate

```
ImagePicker.create(this)
            .folderMode(true) // folder mode (false by default)
            .folderTitle("Folder") // folder selection title
            .imageTitle("Tap to select") // image selection title
            .single() // single mode
          // multi mode (default mode)
            .limit(10) // max images can be selected (99 by default)
            .showCamera(true) // show camera or not (true by default)
            .imageDirectory("Camera") // directory name for captured image  ("Camera" folder by default)
             // original selected images, used in multi mode
            .start(12); // start image picker activity with request code
```

It is working I can see gallery.

onActivityResult:

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        if (requestCode == 12 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_SELECTED_IMAGES);
            // do your logic ....
            imageview.setImageBitmap(images);//It is not working, I know it is not bitmap but how to set?
        }
    }
```

Finally how to set imageview ?

Comment: You can't set an image view to an arraylist of images, you can only set an image view to have one image as a source.

Also, looks like you are processing your images on the main thread, which is also not a good idea.

Comment: So what is the reason of this library?

Comment: Is it not working for my purpose?

Comment: your images are in the Array, but you have to use them on multiple image views or a custom view that displays multiple images

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an image view to an arraylist of images, you can only set an image view to have one image as a source.

Also, looks like you are processing your images on the main thread, which is also not a good idea.

your images are in the Array, but you have to use them on multiple image views or a custom view that displays multiple images

Comment: Thanks for response, Nowadays nobody answer my questions in SO. Performance is the least important thing for this app, maybe I will run this code in background thread. Is this library is not working for my purpose? Is there any way for my purpose?

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. here is one i found by searching 'display gallery of images android'.

http://www.androidinterview.com/android-gallery-view-example-displaying-a-list-of-images/

Comment: But its type is Integer in this library type is Image, it is not working

Comment: use what you have to get your Array of images and use that tutorial to display your images

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap getScreenshot(Image image) {

    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();

    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

    // ??????Bitmap???
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
    image.close();

    return bitmap;
}
```

Image is resource rather than a image but you can use above API to get bitmap by using ByteBuffer. Pass images.get(position) in getScreenshot(Image image). it'll return bitmap then simply set imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
[Example link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.media.Image)